# Función recursiva en PHP para coger los sitemaps

Tags: php, php7, php5

Hace una semana que estoy intentando hacer una función recursiva en `PHP`, que me devuelva un `array` con enlaces a `sitemap` que tengan productos.

Llamada a la función: `sitemap_check("www.example.com/1_index_sitemap.xml");`

Función actualmente:

```
function sitemap_check($url)
{
    print_r($url); 
    $xml = getxml($url);
    if(empty($xml)) return false; 
    $xml = (array)$xml;
    foreach($xml as $tipo=>$enlace)
    {
        if($tipo == "sitemap")
            return sitemap_check($enlace); //Llamada recursiva. 
        else
            return $url;
    }
}
```

La idea es que la función acceda a `www.example.com/1_index_sitemap.xml` y coja el `XML`, lo recorra y coja únicamente los `sitemaps` que tengan productos.

Si dentro de `1_index_sitemap.xml` hay:

```
www.example.com/sitemap_01.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_02.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_03.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_04.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_05.xml
```

Debería llamar a la función recursiva por cada uno de esos, y determinar nuevamente si son productos o otros `sitemap`, es decir, mientras un `xml` tenga dentro de si mismo otros `xml`, debería llamarme a la función recursiva.

No me quiero extender con la explicación y complicarla aún más, si tienen dudas de lo que necesito pueden preguntarme en los comentarios. He intento durante 1 semana y no puedo hacerlo andar.

Posibles estructuras de los sitemaps:

Sitemap que contiene Productos:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/categoria/producto.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-20</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/categoria/producto.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-03-20</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Sitemap que contiene sitemaps:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap_0.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap_1.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap_2.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap_3.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Aclaración: La estructura no siempre es la misma, pueden tener "lastmod", "changefreq", así como no. Lo importante acá es que si antes de "loc" o "url" tiene una etiqueta "sitemap", hay que coger la url dentro de "loc" o "url" y hacer la recursividad, no obstante, si antes de "loc" o "url" hay un "url", significa que es un producto y en ese caso no me interesa la url en si, sino la URL de ese sitemap entero. ¿Me explico?

Retomando el ejemplo anterior, si dentro de 1_index_sitemap.xml hay:

```
www.example.com/sitemap_01.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_02.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_03.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_04.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_05.xml
```

Y dentro de cada uno de esos hay 10 productos, pues yo necesitaria que la función recursiva retorne:

```
www.example.com/sitemap_01.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_02.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_03.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_04.xml
www.example.com/sitemap_05.xml
```

En conclusión: que me retorne enlaces a sitemaps que dentro contengan productos

Comment: ¿Que hace `getxml()`? ¿Comprobaste que  `(array)$xml` contiene algún índice `sitemap`? Visita [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder obtener buenas respuestas que te ayuden.

Comment: Convendría que pongas un ejemplo de la estructura del (los) archivos `.XML` con los que se va a trabajar, para saber cómo habría que leerlos.

Comment: @A.Cedano tendría que servir para todos los sitemaps, hay sitemaps que tienen productos, otros que contienen sitemaps y otros mixtos.

Comment: @Fly getxml() simplemente hace un file_get_contents() pero con algunas opciones que aplico.

Comment: Eso no importa. Tienes que decirnos si esos sitemaps tienen la misma estructura al menos para la parte que te interesa. Si no tienen una estructura homogénea no podrás escribir un código para leer cualquier sitemap.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de poner las posibles estructuras y ejemplos, espero que con esto me puedan ayudar

Comment: *«Lo importante acá es que si antes de "loc" o "url" tiene una etiqueta "sitemap", hay que coger la url dentro de "loc" o "url" y hacer la recursividad...»* No entiendo por qué lo importante sería basar el criterio en si *antes o después de ...*  y no más bien buscar si tiene la estructura `sitemap` directamente ¿?

Comment: Si tiene la estructura "sitemap", significa que habría que coger cada una de esas urls para hacer recursividad, hasta que se encuentren xml que dentro tengan productos.

Comment: Al final nadie me ha ayudado :/